# Transforming data in Django. Want to be able to apply sums to a decimal field

Tags: mysql, django, view, sum, models

I have a model like this.

```
#models.py
class Payment(models.Model):
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    payment_terms = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    VAT = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.unit_price)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment)
    date = models.DateField()
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    work_orders = models.ManyToManyField(Work_Order)
    contract_info = models.ForeignKey(Contract_Info)

    def __unicode__(self):
                return self.invoice_no
```

What I want to focus is payment so try forgetting everything else. Here is my views.py.

```
#views.py
@login_required 
def invoice_details(request, id=1):
    invoices_list = Invoice.objects.filter(pk=id)
    invoice = get_object_or_404(Invoice, pk=id)
    client = invoices_list[0].client
    work_orders = invoices_list[0].work_orders
    payment = invoices_list[0].payment

    return render_to_response(('invoice_details.html', locals()), {'work_orders': work_orders,'payment':payment,'client': client, 'invoice': invoice ,'invoices_list': invoices_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And here is my template.

```
<h1>invoice_details.html<h1>
{{ payment.amount }}
```

The template displays the payment amount in a decimal value. What I want to be able to do is some sums with  {{payment.amount}}. Suppose if I wanted to multiply whatever the value
{{payment.amount}} by let say 2. How would I do this?

Comment: Why are you doing a `.filter()` just to index it, when you do a very similar operation on the very next line?

Comment: I know. never mind about that.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
#views.py
subtotal = payment.amount * 2
return render_to_response(('invoice_details.html', locals()), {'work_orders': work_orders,'payment':payment,'client': client, 'invoice': invoice ,'invoices_list': invoices_list, 'subtotal':subtotal}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In a template put this custom tag (I think that what it is) to represent the value.

```
{{ subtotal }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the view,

```
new_amount = paymount.amount * 2
return render_to_response(('invoice_details.html', locals()), {'work_orders': work_orders,'payment':payment,'client': client, 'invoice': invoice ,'invoices_list': invoices_list, 'new_amount':new_amount}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But if there's some reason you cannot or do not want to, you can acheive something similar in the template by using template tags. I do not think there is a multiply tag, but there is an add:

```
{{ payment.amount|add:"2" }}
```

Would simply add 2 to your payment amount, similarly

```
{{ payment.amount|add:payment.amount }}
```

Would double the value displayed. Adding is likely not exactly what you wanted to do, so you can attempt to make your own template tag to use multiply or whatever function you'd like, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Another problem with this is it rounds the value into a whole number. I wonder why.

Comment: payment.amount is likely a float and the template tag is converting it to an integer

Comment: Is there a way to keep the value as a decimal?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need this to be done inside the *template* and not in the view, but here is my go at a solution. There is a [long discussion about arithmetic in Django templates](http://markmail.org/message/zx4hc7yllwdkbl3b) about not supporting this feature for specifically the use case you described.

If you still want to proceed, this might help. In the Django docs, there is an [`|add` built-in template filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) that seems to be a primitive form of arithmetic. Unfortunately, there is no `|multiply` filter. You can probably find the filter in the `template/defaultfilters.py` under your Django installation.

Copy it, change what you need to make it a product instead of a sum. When you're done, you might want to submit it to the Django project to make it a buil-tin in future releases.

Comment: How would I have to do it in a view?